# Numbered paragraphs or lines in epub?

Tags: epub, editing, formatting

In some books (namely, The Iliad, The Bible, Seneca's Letters) I've seen paragraphs, lines or sentences are numbered.

There is a couple of books I'd like to have properly formatted, and they have just that enumeration. Unfortunately, I don't know the term for this and can't find out what's the correct way to do that in `epub`.

Should these be just regular text or is there a tag for them?

Comment: One bodge that comes to mind is using a numbered list... but that would be horribly, horribly ugly.

Comment: It is not semantically a list, it's prose, so paragraphs shoudln't be list elements.

Comment: Of course you're right (and that's why I put that as a comment rather than an answer), but it might do the job in a pinch. I'm sure there are better ways, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can download a free version of Dante's *Divine Comedy* from ReadBeyond ([Inferno](https://www.readbeyond.it/ebooks/f3b20d25.html), [Purgatorio](https://www.readbeyond.it/ebooks/ad4e2201.html), [Paradiso](https://www.readbeyond.it/ebooks/06003b99.html)), these are well formatted epubs that also have numbered lines. You may find useful to look inside them and check their structure, to see if you can replicate these CSS settings for your own needs.

Comment: A great answer! The book, indeed, is very well formatted, and also has comments and illustration, so I can lookup how to deal with these. Having an id for each sentence is also a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think currently there's no way to embed enumeration in paragraphs, but here's what seems to be recommended for poetry (and I think it applies to ancient philosophy as well): http://bencrowder.net/blog/2011/06/formatting-poetry-epub-kindle/

TL:DR - numbers go to separate `span` of class `num` and have their own CSS definitions. I'll go with that and see how it renders in readers I use.

Comment: I'd suggest giving the `<span>`s an id in addition to a class; that would allow you to link to any particular line number later on with hyperlinks.

Comment: It's a good idea! Once the formatting is done, I'll feed the directory to a Perl script which would do it for me.

Comment: Should be able to do it with a simple RegEx, really; no need to do it with Perl.

Comment: I think having TT or erb template is a great idea anyway. It's reuseable, and you can pass some options to the script, etc. As a rule, whenever it's more than a simple substitution in one file, I reach for Perl or Ruby.

Comment: Sure; whatever works best for you is definitely the best way to go. For me, I like being able to just paste in a pre-written RegEx to the find and replace box, but that's just my preference.